# Designation for the behaviour of a person that acts in a club-like manner

Tags: single-word-requests, translation

I would like to find a proper term for designating club behaviour, that is, when people of some team/club are favorable to anything associated with their team simply because it is their team and against anything associated with others because they are not.

For instance, in Portuguese, such term would be "comportamento clubístico", which I would translate to English as "clubbistic behaviour". However, I cannot find the term "clubbistic" in the English dictionary. There is probably a better one to represent this meaning.

Comment: Élio, poxa, me parece um pouco exagerado. No, in English clubistic is not a word. And though there are football (soccer) clubs, that's mostly in the UK. In American English, maybe team favoritism.

Comment: In Italian "ultras" might be used, I don't know if it translates into English, it is associated with zealous behaviour and typical acts of violence by football 'supporters' vandals.

Comment: We use ***clannish*** rather than ***clubbish / club-like / club-centric / ...*** for such contexts.

Answer (score 31, accepted):

**[Tribal](https://www.collinsdictionary.com/dictionary/english/tribal)** would fit, though looking at [Collins](https://www.collinsdictionary.com/dictionary/english/tribal) and others it would seem to mainly have British usage in that manner. The US seems to predominantly use it for *actual* tribes.

> 2. displaying loyalty to a tribe, group, or tribal values
>    *the tribal loyalties of Labour MPs*

In the UK, this is often used in association with adherence to a political party or following a particular sports team.

I did manage to find what I think is a US article covering it, so perhaps it does have more international usage than some of the dictionaries would tell.
Forbes - [Tribalism In Football, Society And Business](https://www.forbes.com/sites/billconerly/2018/08/18/tribalism-in-football-society-and-business/)

Comment: "Tribal" works fine in the US as well.

Comment: @fectin - glad to know, thanks. Whilst I was looking through the usual online dictionaries this secondary meaning was either not mentioned, glossed-over, or in the case of Collins attributed as British usage (& not mentioned in the US usage section).

Comment: I upvoted for the sole reason that the definition seems to fit the purpose, even if it would not be my go-to word for the situation.

Answer (score 13):

As an American, "fanatical" comes to mind. We even call people like in your example "fans".

In politics, the term "partisan" is commonly used to denote the "always my team" mentality.

Comment: "Fanatical" also reminds me of "cultist", although that's specifically about a cult.

Comment: While the term "fanatical" probably originally meant exactly this, I think it now has significant connotations of obsession to it.  It's not just being partisan to one group, it's being so obsessive that you behave inappropriately or go to extreme measures to support your group or attack the opposing group.

Comment: Depending on context, fanatical can mean extremist zealotry, or it can mean enthusiastic follower. People often describe themselves as fanatical about some entertainer or team without meaning the extremism of a cult member.

Answer (score 5):

When speaking of a sport team, this kind of allegiance or devotion to the club may be translated as **fan mentality**.

Example : *There are times when sport reporters have to put the fan mentality aside and make newspaper articles based more on evidence than on personal taste.*

Comment: Some related terms: "_pack mentality_", "_mob mentality_", "_herd mentality_", "_group mentality_", and "_in-group mentality_".

Answer (score 5):

In the domain of cognitive bias, you have **[in-group favoritism](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/In-group_favoritism)**, which Wikipedia describes as:

> a pattern of favoring members of one's in-group over out-group
> members. This can be expressed in evaluation of others, in allocation
> of resources, and in many other ways.

The direct opposite is **[reactive devaluation](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Reactive_devaluation)**, which Wikipedia describes as:

> a cognitive bias that occurs when a proposal is devalued if it appears
> to originate from an antagonist.

Comment: In the unlikely even that the downvoter would see this: what should I improve to make this answer useful?

Comment: I'm not the downvoter, but maybe because no one would use either of these terms outside of a research paper?  This sounds about as foreign to me as "clubistic".

Comment: @GentlePurpleRain I usually use them to talk with my acquaintances about the principles, a bit like when explaining a figure of speech. But yeah, I see what you mean.

Answer (score 4):

**chauvinistic behaviour**

> **chauvinism** noun chau·​vin·​ism ˈshō-və-ˌni-zəm
> Synonyms of chauvinism
>
> 1 : an attitude of superiority toward members of the opposite sex male
> chauvinism also : behavior expressive of such an attitude
>
> **2 : undue partiality or attachment to a group or place to which one belongs or has belonged** regional chauvinism
>
> https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/chauvinistic

Comment: This is actually the original meaning of chauvinism, before it became strongly associated with belief in male superiority. Unfortunately not everyone will recognize that meaning.

Answer (score 4):

Depending on the specific context, the word **cliquey** might be a good fit.

> If you describe a group of people or their behaviour as cliquey, you
> mean they spend their time only with other members of the group and
> seem unfriendly towards people who are not in the group. [*Collins Dictionary*](https://www.collinsdictionary.com/dictionary/english/cliquey)

Answer (score 2):

'Clubby' is a correct English adjective.

> Pervaded by the characteristics of the club. Also, friendly, sociable

[Oxford English Dictionary](https://www.oed.com/view/Entry/34802?redirectedFrom=clubby#eid)

The OED states it as American English.

> 1918   ‘I. Hay’ Last Million xv. 243   It's a darned sight easier to keep on clubby terms with an Ally whose language you don't know than an Ally whose language you do.

The Ngram shows increasing, then slightly decreasing, use around the turn of this century.

[Ngram - 'clubby'](https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=clubby&year_start=1800&year_end=2019&corpus=en-2019&smoothing=3)

Comment: The only issue is the word club itself. In soccer, in the US, it does not work very well.

Comment: In my experience, *clubby* refers only to one specific kind of *club* — social clubs, in the tradition of upper-class London clubs and their inheritors elsewhere.  So it’s a good word when that kind of club is involved, but has totally different connotations from the football club culture that OP describes.

Comment: @PLL Yes for the UK in both cases.l

Answer (score 2):

"**biased**" (adj), though not specific to human behavior, may fit the bill.

- characterized by bias, having a tendency to prefer one person or thing to another, and to favor that person or thing.   A biased opinion, behavior, result.

> **If someone is biased**, they prefer one group of people to another, and behave unfairly as a result. You can also say that a process or system is biased.
>
> - "He seemed a bit biased against women in my opinion." [+ against/in favour of]
> - "...the perception that the justice system is biased in favour of the offender rather than the victim."
> - The judge was biased.

Synonyms: prejudiced, weighted, one-sided, partial

[Collins](https://www.collinsdictionary.com/dictionary/english/biased)

Answer (score 0):

Although it's an obvious borrowing from French and uncommon in colloquial speech, the phrase **esprit de corps** is probably a good candidate.

Comment: esprit de corps seems to have too positive a meaning for what the OP requires.

Comment: esprit de corps - "a feeling of pride, fellowship, and common loyalty shared by the members of a particular group"

OP - "when people of some team/club are favorable to anything associated with their team simply because it is their team"

You may not feel this is the absolute best choice, but it is far too close to deserve a downvote.

Comment: I'm downvoting because it's wrong. The members of a sports team might have esprit de corps, but the fans wouldn't. It's a term that comes from military units, so it wouldn't apply to fans like this.

Comment: @nick012000 First of all, OP was not clear about any such distinction, said "when people of some team/club." No mention of just the fans. Secondly, arguing based on the *origin* of a term is just fallacious. Thirdly, I literally included the modern definition. The term could apply just as it applies in political writings to describe in-group vs out-group bias and enthusiasm.

Comment: I agree this captures the positive aspect of what the OP is after, but not the negative. One can experience esprit de corps without having an "antagonist" group that is actively disliked. It implies only that the group members have common positive feelings about their group, not that they also have common negative feelings about another group.

Comment: i would translate "esprit de corps" to mean something like "sense of community"

Answer (score 0):

A bit more on the slang side, but I've often heard this referred to as **homerism**.

> **Homerism**
>
> In sportcasting, having a bias toward your hometown team or toward the team for which you play/used to play.
>
> *The local newspapers practice homerism, predicting that the hometown teams will win and complaining about the refs when the local teams lose.*

[Urban Dictionary](https://www.urbandictionary.com/define.php?term=Homerism)